# iPhone loads Wi-Fi captive portal page over 3G (iOS 6)

Tags: ios, iphone, 3g

I've made a captive portal using iptables NAT redirection and white-listed MACs. This works nicely, and iDevices pop up my login/terms page after association. However, I've noticed that when 3G is enabled, the phone tries to load this page over 3G, which leaves users staring at a white screen.

One possible solution I've found is to white-list www.apple.com so that the iPhone can retrieve www.apple.com/library/test/success.html, so it thinks it's connected to the Internet, and then when users go to Safari the login page shows up. This works but leaves users confused, and I much prefer the login page popping up automatically.

Is there any way to tell the iPhone to load the login page over Wi-Fi at all times *and* also have the login page popping up?

Answer (score 0):

So far, we've not found any way of changing the behaviour of the 'iDevices'.  For some reason, they *need* to talk to Apple before they'll let you talk to anything else.  Nice one Apple, thanks for thinking about enterprise environments...

I think your solution there is about as good as you'll get - we've had to do similar things.  They're workarounds, not real solutions as such - that'll only come from Apple, long term.